# Is there a way to set the DPI of output pdf using FPDF library?

Tags: php, fpdf

Is there a way to reduce the DPI of an output pdf without affecting its size using FPDF library?

Comment: how can you reduce the DPI of anything without affecting the size??

Comment: I'm pretty sure PDF's do not have a resolution, however image objects within them do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, PDF documents do not have DPI settings, given that they are vector objects. I assume you actually refer to embedded raster images (JPEG, GIF...). In that case, just check the [documentation for the Image() function](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm): forth and fifth parameters (`$w` and `$h`) can express the desired DPI if you write a negative value:

```
// Insert a logo in the top-left corner at 300 dpi
$pdf->Image('logo.png',10,10,-300);
```

Answer (score 0):

No. But if you're thinking of reducing size of the document, you could use FPDF SetCompression() method:

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetCompression(true);
```

There are more details on their webpage, in "Manual" section: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/setcompression.htm.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toMM($v) {
   return ($v * 26.2) / 25.4;
}
```

http://www.dallinjones.com/2008/07/how-to-convert-from-pixels-to-millimeters/comment-page-1/#comment-1079

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to set up the conversion px -> mm in mPdf:

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=449

http://mpdf1.com/manual/index.php?tid=148